# Javascript How to show message on hover to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover, mouse

I can show image warning with below codes.If username or password is empty.

I want to show message , if mouse on hover to warning image.

For Example;

"UserName Can Not Be Empty!" for UserName and "Password Can Not Be Empty!" for Password.

Where to edit for showing message on hover to image with mouse?

My Javascript Code:

```
function LoginButonOnclick() {
  var data= {
  UserName: $('#UserNameTextBox').val(),
  Password: $('#PasswordTextBox').val(),
  };
  if (data.UserName== null) {
    $("#showwarning1").html('<img src="~/Image/warning.png">');
  }
  if (data.Password== null) {
    $("#showwarning2").html('<img src="~/Image/warning.png" />');
  }
}
```

My Html Code:

```
<input type="text" id="UsernameTextBox" name="UsernameTextBox"/>
<input type="text" id="PasswordTextBox" name="PasswordTextBox"/>
<input type="button" onclick="LoginButonOnclick()" value="Enter"/>

<div id="showwarning1"></div>
<div id="showwarning2"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why to go and complicate things for yourself.... Its so simple...
use the **title** attribute of `<img>` tag to show mouse hover messages!!

```
<img src="~/Image/warning.png" title="Password is empty!!"/>
```

Comment: Why would anyone do it any other way for a small note?

Answer (score 2):

you can consider using the jqueryUI tooltip widget.

Refer: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

alternatively use the hover event :http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onmouseover attribute to call the same function, so that it will do the same thing on hover as on click.

```
  function LoginButonOnclick() {
  var data= {
  UserName: $('#UserNameTextBox').val(),
  Password: $('#PasswordTextBox').val(),
  };
  if (data.UserName== null) {
    $("#showwarning1").html('<img src="~/Image/warning.png">');
  }
  if (data.Password== null) {
    $("#showwarning2").html('<img src="~/Image/warning.png" />');
  }
}
<input type="text" id="UsernameTextBox" name="UsernameTextBox"/>
    <input type="text" id="PasswordTextBox" name="PasswordTextBox"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="LoginButonOnclick()" onmouseover="LoginButonOnclick()" value="Enter"/>

    <div id="showwarning1"></div>
    <div id="showwarning2"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could also use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily by using jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $("#showwarning1").on('mouseover', function(){
  //show error message to the user
  console.log("UserName Can Not Be Empty!");

 });

 $("#showwarning2").on('mouseover', function(){
  //show error message to the user
  console.log("Password Can Not Be Empty!");
 });
});
```